# How to create a multiple gate component (like quad opamp), but hidden the power pins in all but one gate in Proteus?

Tags: operational-amplifier, digital-logic, schematics, proteus

I noticed that some opamps from the standard library can hide the power pins in the elements from the second one to the last (image 1), but other components do not. While creating my own opamp i tried to add this feature but no success at all. Can anybody help me if there is an option or even add some line to the "Script block"?

[image: Image 1]

I'm using Proteus 8.1

Comment: I would look for an example in the standard library. May be there is an example for a quad nand gate or other logic. Did you read the manual, there should be an example?

Comment: @Uwe I tried to recreate the LT1014 as an example. I could change the name and keep the hidden power pin feature. But when I changed the package to a custom one, the feature desapeared. Seems like there is something to do with the package too. No mentios for this specific feature in the manual

Comment: Some CAD systems use different schematic symbols, one symbol with power pins and another without. I would recommend searching all available documentation for an example.